# Wysiwyg in views module

Tags: views, entities, blocks, wysiwyg

Can I add a wysiwyg field in Views so that users can write and post text on my page?

Would I need to enable this as a block?

I have installed ckeditor and views already.

Answer (score 0):

The only way WYSIWYG works with Views is with either an embedded comment or using the [Editable Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/editableviews) module:

> Editable Views lets you create Views where the fields can be edited.
>   Fields show both the current value and a form to edit it. A 'Save'
>   button allows saving of all the entities shown in the View.
>
> Editable fields can be added on the base entity as well as on entities
>   brought into the View by a relationship. Other, non-editable fields
>   may be added to the View, in which case they function normally.